# Docker install root certificate

Tags: windows, docker, .net-core, certificate

I have a dotnetcore web.api application that runs in docker. 
I'm using the windows version and not the linux version. I'm using the image microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1709

This application calls an external api (https) and I get an error saying the SSL verification failed. After some googling I found out that my enterprise's root certificate must also be available in the container.

I tried it first with Powershell using the Import-Certificate command. But this failed. It seems Powershell is not present in the image. I then found this [blogpost](https://joshuachini.com/2018/02/08/how-to-import-an-enterprise-certificate-into-a-windows-container/). But Certoc is also not present on the image and I can't find a place where to download this.

Is there a way to install the certificate using the image microsoft/dotnet? Or do i have to use the microsoft/windowsservercore image?

Comment: Any resolution ?

Comment: nope. Used a linux container instead and copied the root cert to default location (/etc/ssl/certs/cacert)

Answer (score -2):

I might be misunderstanding the need, but if you have the certificate file you can `COPY` it to the docker container.

1. Add the (something).cert file to your project
2. In your `Dockerfile` add the line
3. `COPY ./(something).cert (path/to/cert/location/in/container)`
4. Start your docker container

Let me know if I can clarify anything in my answer i'm happy to update it.

Comment: doesn't a certificate need to be installed?  I didn't know you can just copy it somewhere. I thought those things were registered in the registry. and where would I copy it to?

I need my enterprise root certificate in the container so the call I make to my other api (https and not running in docker) from within the container can verify the ssl connection that needs to be made

Comment: In windows the process is alittle more UI registry focused as you mention.  Hoever containers are linux based, and that means having a file in the expected location.  Here is another S.O. post about the same thing and you can see the solution worked for them as well.  Having the `.crt` file in the right location (and permissions) is all it take in linux. -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using a windows container and not a linux container. Every example I find is how you do it in a linux container and not a windows container.

Comment: -1 because in Windows containers you don't get a `/path/to/cert/location` that _just works_. You have to somehow add the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities.