# How to use non default ca certs for dotnet core and nuget?

Tags: ssl, .net-core, nuget

My company use its own ssl certificates when communicating to internet, the command line e.g. `dotnet add package` will failed to run:

```
error: Unable to load the service index for source 
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
error:   Authentication failed, see inner exception.
error:   The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

Is there anyway to let dotnet tool and libraries use an alternate cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, there is an intermediary in your company which encapsulates all connections with company SSL, thus Nuget cannot trust your SSL certificate (It thinks that there is a man in the middle which causes security hole).

you may want to check [Issue #4387](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4387)  and [Issue 5773](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5773)

You may consider to fork Nuget Repository to disable SSL Enforcement.

Also, AFAIK `SSL_CERT_DIR` and `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variables are supported starting from .Net Core  2.1 [[3]](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4387#issuecomment-279112770)

Comment: Any chance you want to improve on this a little rather than just linking to the issues?  It may be the correct answer but as its written its a bit hard to understand what you think the problem is and how you intend they should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate a little bit here. Recently been working on containerization of one of the apps and since there was private nuget repo used as well as `nuget.org` what we ended up doing is copying nuget config file with all the repos and copying certificate crt file.

If you have only one repo server (under one domain) then you can use `SSL_CERT_FILE` variable that will contain the path to certificate's crt file.

If you have several repo servers like in my case (nuget.org and one private) then you should you `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variable. It should be set to directory where the certs for all repos are. Usually you don't need the cert for nuget.org. The reason you can't use `SSL_CERT_FILE` variable in this case is that it will try it for nuget.org as well and will fail. so, `SSL_CERT_DIR` was the solution in our case with just one crt file for private repo.

then `dotnet restore --configfile nuget.config` stopped complaining

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue when try to build aspnet:7.0 docker container.

My company has decryption proxy, so all certificates are generated on the fly (man in the middle).

I was able to fix thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42292623/1768591) in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image)

```
ADD your_ca_root.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt && update-ca-certificates
```

If running plain linux, then this should work

```
copy your_ca_root.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt
chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt && update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: This was helpful and so was [How to add trusted root CA to Docker alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67231714/97803)

Comment: I found [this documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) on update-ca-certificates to be useful since it explains why you are putting certs in your user folder.  The command does not seem to be specific to Ubuntu since I've found docs for it in Debian Linux as well.