# What version of tomcat/java docker should I use for java version 1.8?

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, version

Currently the top of my docker image is this:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8
```

This docker image is consuming a ton of memory. Could that be because the incorrect version?

Answer (score 0):

`tomcat:8-jre8` is a very huge image. You can reduce image size significantly by using the `alpine` or `slim` version.

```
docker pull tomcat:8-jre8-alpine
```

Check the comparison `8-jre8` and `8-jre8-alpine` tags below

[image]

Have a look at other available options: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat?tab=tags&page=1&name=8-jre8

Comment: Do you know where certs would go?
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: @dropkick you can pass it in `vm` arguments while running the programming. `java MyClass -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path to cacert file"`

Comment: I need to do it in the dockerfile. Or is this not possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image

Comment: Yea I was able to get this to work. But I guess something with my java/angular must be causing the high memory. Idk if you know much about what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if, in your case, you **must** use Tommy but, if you just want a web server you may want to try using a jre8 image that uses **jetty** such as https://hub.docker.com/_/jetty or another good one is **undertow**.  Basically TommyCAT is very big whereas Jetty or Undertow are smaller web servers.  See if you can't update your FROM... line and try jetty or undertow and see if you get better memory usage.