# The remote certificate is invalid only for .net core app on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, ssl, .net-core

I have a dotnet core app that through a controller=>action makes an external request to a S3 bucket.
In this way:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUSouth1))
{
   return await client.GetObjectAsync(request);
}
```

When I make a request to the end point that executes this code, I get a successful outcome on both Mac and Windows.
The problem comes when I make a Linux container for the app (the goal is to deploy this container), in that case I get the following exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: The linux image don't have the CA, so you must install yourself. Se [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image)

Comment: thanks. Also as workaround I am using http.