# ssl/tls handshake failed on docker container from asp.net core api 3.1

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ssl, asp.net-web-api, tls1.2

I have an asp.net core 3.1 API and it run on docker container. Docker work on Linux server and when asp.net Core API try to connect to Microsoft SQL Server (work on Window Server 2016) get an error like this:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption( ssl /tls) handshake failed)**

API work on http but API Gateway is https.

Comment: How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Who is the SSL certificate provider for API Gateway? is it trusted in your browser?

Comment: Our DevOps team host APIs and Gateway on local company servers. On Postman when I open SSL certificate give me this warning;  SSL Error: Self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: That is your cause, docker containers do not trust self-signed certificates by default.

Comment: Maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image

Comment: Did you found answer to this issue ?

Comment: Yes, you can research Kestrel for api.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support TLS 1.2

Recommended Solution: Install the latest updates on supported versions of SQL Server1 and ensure the TLS 1.2 protocol is enabled on the server.

**Insecure solution: Configure TLS/SSL settings in the docker image/client environment to connect with TLS 1.0.**

Change content of following file: **/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf**

Replace following:

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

With following:

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

With following dockerfile command:

```
RUN sed -i 's/^MinProtocol\s*=.*$/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf && \
    sed -i 's/^CipherString\s*=.*$/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#possible-reasons-and-solutions