# how to keep layers when do `docker load` (no squash)

Tags: docker

currently we are using `docker 19.03.15`;

- we use `docker build -t test:test .` to get image `test:test` (`docker image history test:test` A)
- we use `docker save -o out.tar test:test` to get `out.tar`
- we use `docker rmi test:test` to remove original image
- we use `docker load -i out.tar` to get `test:test` back (`docker image history test:test` B)

and for the probe of A and B of `docker image history`, we find that at B, there is only one image layer meanwhile the others are `<missing>`; checked in `docker run` and all contents are there, which means that docker combine all layers into one!

my question is: **How to tell docker to load image from the tar ball and keep the layers?**

for layer, I mean, where there is a command in Dockerfile, there is a layer, e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim # create one layer
RUN apt-get install -y python3               # create another layer
```

after `docker build`, use `docker image history` can see

```
IMAGE      | CREATED BY
hash1      | |0 /bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3
hash2      | |0 /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
hash3      | ... (base image last command)
<missing>  | ...
```

after `docker load`, `docker image history` will show

```
IMAGE      | CREATED BY
hashx      | |0 /bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3
<missing>  | |0 /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
<missing>  | ... (base image last command)
<missing>  | ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hacker way: we can directly operate in `/var/lib/docker` to dump image data and remove layers that we want.

Comment: How to do this? How to properly place save.tar files into `/var/lib/docker`?