# How do I add a CA root certificate with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose

I am new to docker so forgive me if I miss something obvious.

Basically, I am having a similiar issue as [How do I add a CA root certificate inside a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image). I am running a web service but need access to HTTPS servers that is internal with a certificate signed by my company. The certificates came preinstalled with my machine but I don't think that matters for docker. I tried following the solution but I am using a docker-compose and I feel like it doesn't reflect the changes made in the Dockerfile. Overall, I am mostly asking about:

1. How do I add .cer CA certificates to my docker
2. How come I don't see any changes after changing the Dockerfile and running docker-compose up

Comment: Are you using the compose file to build the image? Can you show the relevant section of your compose file?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the cert file into the Docker container by using volume.
`volumes: local path:container path`