# vscode dev container doesn't install extensions, behind corporate proxy

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, zscaler

I have been trying to set up a dev container for a c++ project but cannot get vscode to install the extensions I've listed in my .devcontainer/devcontainer.json file.

I am behind a corporate proxy (zscaler).
I have acquired a CA certificate and copied it into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image).
I confirmed the certificate was added by following [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97244/list-all-available-ssl-ca-certificates).
I have added proxy settings in my docker-compose.yml and my user settings.json file as per [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120332).

settings.json:

```json
{
  "http.proxy": "http://localhost:80",
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  embedded:
    container_name: build_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      - http_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:80
      - https_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:443
```

Note that I used port numbers posted on
[zscaler's website](https://help.zscaler.com/zia/configuring-firewall-policies#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20Zscaler%20service,Port%20443%20for%20HTTPS%20traffic).

And I have listed the extensions I am trying to install in the .devcontainer.json file:

```json
{
    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "twxs.cmake",
                "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
                "josetr.cmake-language-support-vscode",
                "ms-vscode.cpptools",
                "ms-vscode.docker",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
                "fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight",
                "cschlosser.doxdocgen",
                "mhutchie.git-graph",
                "albert.tabout",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
                "ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack",
                "marus25.cortex-debug"
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

This is the output I get when I open the dev container. At the bottom, it reports it has established a connection, but does not seem to install anything.

```
[147 ms] Dev Containers 0.275.1 in VS Code 1.75.1 (441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf).
[145 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[334 ms] Setting up container for folder or workspace: c:\sw\sw0498
[347 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[348 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[792 ms] Server API version: 1.41
[795 ms] Start: Run: docker volume ls -q
[1238 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.folder=c:\sw\sw0498 --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[1700 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\sw\sw0498 --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2339 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e
[2877 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\sw\sw0498
[3313 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e
[3741 ms] Start: Run: C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\Gduddridge\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.275.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-0327dd97-9f05-4d50-9aad-362e3dbbd3d21677285351669 --workspace-folder c:\sw\sw0498 --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\sw\sw0498 --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true --terminal-columns 203 --terminal-rows 18
[4381 ms] (node:3664) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[4382 ms] (Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[4385 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.29.0. Node.js v16.14.2. win32 10.0.19044 x64.
[4385 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx version
[5015 ms] github.com/docker/buildx v0.10.0 876462897612d36679153c3414f7689626251501
[5016 ms] 
[5016 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[5029 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose version --short
[5726 ms] Docker Compose version: 2.15.1
[5728 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=sw0498 --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=embedded
[6056 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e
[6386 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose -f c:\sw\sw0498\docker-compose.yml -f c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\docker-compose.yml --profile * config
[7005 ms] name: sw0498
services:
  embedded:
    build:
      context: c:\sw\sw0498
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - while sleep 1000; do :; done
    container_name: build_container
    environment:
      http_proxy: http://host.docker.internal:80
      https_proxy: http://host.docker.internal:443
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: c:\sw
      target: /workspaces
      bind:
        create_host_path: true
networks:
  default:
    name: sw0498_default
[7014 ms] Start: Run: docker events --format {{json .}} --filter event=start
[7058 ms] PersistedPath=c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data, ContainerHasLabels=true
[7058 ms] Container was created with these config files: c:\sw\sw0498\docker-compose.yml,c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\docker-compose.yml,c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1677279265598.yml,c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1677279268033.yml
[7059 ms] Restoring c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1677279265598.yml from persisted storage
[7060 ms] Restoring c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1677279268033.yml from persisted storage
[7060 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose --project-name sw0498 -f c:\sw\sw0498\docker-compose.yml -f c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\docker-compose.yml -f c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1677279265598.yml -f c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\docker-compose\docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1677279268033.yml up -d --no-recreate

[+] Running 1/1
 - Container build_container  Started                                                                                                                                                                 0.9s
[9208 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=sw0498 --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=embedded
[9491 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e
[9828 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[9828 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e8a136b73fdda8ba15eec39462828b184dec27df29a0332c036df
[10207 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[10247 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[10701 ms] x86_64
[10701 ms] 
[10702 ms] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[10707 ms] PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
[10708 ms] 
[10708 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[10713 ms] Start: Run in container: test -f '/var/devcontainer/.patchEtcEnvironmentMarker'
[10718 ms] 
[10718 ms] 
[10718 ms] Start: Run in container: test -f '/var/devcontainer/.patchEtcProfileMarker'
[10724 ms] 
[10724 ms] 
[10753 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e8a136b73fdda8ba15eec39462828b184dec27df29a0332c036df
[11052 ms] Start: Run: C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\Gduddridge\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.275.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder c:\sw\sw0498 --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\sw\sw0498 --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --container-id bedcdcef496e8a136b73fdda8ba15eec39462828b184dec27df29a0332c036df --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --mount-workspace-git-root true
[11602 ms] (node:16776) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[11602 ms] (Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[11608 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.29.0. Node.js v16.14.2. win32 10.0.19044 x64.
[11608 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e8a136b73fdda8ba15eec39462828b184dec27df29a0332c036df
[11904 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose version --short
[12518 ms] Start: Run: C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\Gduddridge\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.275.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder c:\sw\sw0498 --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\sw\sw0498 --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --container-id bedcdcef496e8a136b73fdda8ba15eec39462828b184dec27df29a0332c036df --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\sw\sw0498\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --include-merged-configuration --mount-workspace-git-root true
[13413 ms] (node:23264) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[13413 ms] (Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[13426 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.29.0. Node.js v16.14.2. win32 10.0.19044 x64.
[13426 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e8a136b73fdda8ba15eec39462828b184dec27df29a0332c036df
[13783 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[13784 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container bedcdcef496e8a136b73fdda8ba15eec39462828b184dec27df29a0332c036df
[14117 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[14170 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[14557 ms] x86_64
[14557 ms] 
[14558 ms] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[14565 ms] PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
[14566 ms] 
[14567 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[14574 ms] Start: Setup shutdown monitor
[14576 ms] Forking shutdown monitor: c:\Users\Gduddridge\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.275.1\dist\shutdown\shutdownMonitorProcess \\.\pipe\vscode-remote-containers-506b99ad1fcfc211788834076e9580938fed653c-sock dockerCompose Debug c:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20230224T163510\window1\exthost\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers 1677285353698
[14608 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server
[14639 ms] 
[14640 ms] 
[14641 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[14648 ms] 
[14649 ms] 
[14650 ms] Exit code 1
[14650 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json
[14659 ms] 
[14660 ms] cat: /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json: No such file or directory
[14660 ms] Exit code 1
[14661 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/bin/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
[14677 ms] 
[14677 ms] 
[14678 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
[14695 ms] 
[14695 ms] 
[14696 ms] Start: Run in container: touch '/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf'
[14698 ms] Start: Launching Dev Containers helper.
[14702 ms] ssh-agent: SSH_AUTH_SOCK in container (/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-ae25993f01fb68030d008f6a89607c8a1ba3a4a7.sock) forwarded to local host (\\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent).
[14702 ms] X11 forwarding: DISPLAY not set on host.
[14703 ms] Start: Run: gpgconf --list-dir agent-extra-socket
[14705 ms] 
[14705 ms] 
[14862 ms] findLocalWindowsExecutable: Exectuable 'gpgconf' not found on PATH 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\IVI\bin;C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\IVI\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\;C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Win64\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\Gduddridge\scoop\apps\openssl\current\bin;C:\Users\Gduddridge\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\Gduddridge\scoop\apps\oh-my-posh\current\bin;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\;C:\Users\Gduddridge\scoop\shims;C:\Ruby27-x64\bin;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin_;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\mingw\mingw32\bin;C:\Ninja_;C:\cygwin64\bin_;C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin_;C:\cygwin64_;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Programs\Git;C:\Users\Gduddridge\bin;C:\uncrustify-0.74.0_f-win32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6;C:\Users\Gduddridge\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;'.
[14864 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v docker >/dev/null 2>&1
[14873 ms] 
[14874 ms] 
[14874 ms] Exit code 127
[14877 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[14880 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[14881 ms] Start: Run in container: test -f '/tmp/devcontainers-0327dd97-9f05-4d50-9aad-362e3dbbd3d21677285351669/env-loginInteractiveShell.json'
[14889 ms] 
[14890 ms] 
[14890 ms] Exit code 1
[14891 ms] Start: Run in container: # Test for /root/.ssh/known_hosts and ssh
[14891 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[14893 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[14897 ms] /root/.ssh/known_hosts exists
[14897 ms] 
[14898 ms] Exit code 1
[14899 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --system --replace-all credential.helper '!f() { /root/.vscode-server/bin/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-ae25993f01fb68030d008f6a89607c8a1ba3a4a7.js git-credential-helper $*; }; f' || true
[14912 ms] 
[14913 ms] 
[14914 ms] Start: Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink /proc/$pid/cwd ; readlink /proc/$pid/ns/mnt ; cat /proc/$pid/stat | tr "
[14984 ms] Start: Run in container: echo ~
[14989 ms] Start: Run in container: cat '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf' 2>/dev/null || (umask 377 && echo '8270a040-4bcb-4de1-8a6e-f93c826a1983' >'/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf-aa94c597-62ff-4be7-b337-18d0833c3332' && mv -n '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf-aa94c597-62ff-4be7-b337-18d0833c3332' '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf' && rm -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf-aa94c597-62ff-4be7-b337-18d0833c3332' && cat '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf')
[14995 ms] 99262be2-6054-4f0a-aee5-2d08deb2ef37
[14995 ms] 
[14997 ms] Start: Starting VS Code Server
[14998 ms] Start: Preparing Extensions
[15001 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[15007 ms] 
[15008 ms] 
[15008 ms] Exit code 1
[15014 ms] Extensions cache, install extensions: None
[15014 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache && ls /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[15025 ms] 7a4f9c9f-6469-42ae-99dd-bcb25829464d
9ce189bf-ddc1-453d-91e5-5ba2acaddc2f
a946830d-1ace-48ae-818f-12de29255f9d
c0af8b91-f7e4-40a5-9c54-a5263fb7a123
c1ccc80f-8474-4a5a-bc90-bdbd122ed85a
c8e86438-f36a-446b-8de0-a839950cd316
d314f8cd-f982-46b2-90e1-cbcb1066788e
ms-python.isort-2022.8.0
ms-python.python-2023.2.0
ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.2.30
ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap-1.0.0
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.14
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags-0.1.6
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow-0.1.5
njpwerner.autodocstring-0.6.1
[15025 ms] 
[15026 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /vscode/vscode-server/extensionsCache && ls /vscode/vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[15035 ms] 7a4f9c9f-6469-42ae-99dd-bcb25829464d
9ce189bf-ddc1-453d-91e5-5ba2acaddc2f
a946830d-1ace-48ae-818f-12de29255f9d
c0af8b91-f7e4-40a5-9c54-a5263fb7a123
c1ccc80f-8474-4a5a-bc90-bdbd122ed85a
c8e86438-f36a-446b-8de0-a839950cd316
d314f8cd-f982-46b2-90e1-cbcb1066788e
ms-python.isort-2022.8.0
ms-python.isort-2022.8.0.sigzip
ms-python.python-2023.2.0
ms-python.python-2023.2.0.sigzip
ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.2.30
ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.2.30.sigzip
ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206
ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206.sigzip
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap-1.0.0
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap-1.0.0.sigzip
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.14
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.14.sigzip
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags-0.1.6
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow-0.1.5
njpwerner.autodocstring-0.6.1
njpwerner.autodocstring-0.6.1.sigzip
[15036 ms] 
[15037 ms] Extensions cache, link in container: None
[15039 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf/bin/code-server --log debug --force-disable-user-env --server-data-dir /root/.vscode-server --use-host-proxy --telemetry-level all --accept-server-license-terms --host 127.0.0.1 --port 0 --connection-token-file /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf --extensions-download-dir /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --start-server --disable-websocket-compression
[15531 ms] /root
[15532 ms] 
[15533 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-ae25993f01fb68030d008f6a89607c8a1ba3a4a7.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-ae25993f01fb68030d008f6a89607c8a1ba3a4a7.js
[15538 ms] 
[15539 ms] 
[15540 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-ae25993f01fb68030d008f6a89607c8a1ba3a4a7.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-ae25993f01fb68030d008f6a89607c8a1ba3a4a7.js_1677285369238
[15551 ms] 
[15552 ms] 
[15737 ms] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.dotnet/tools'
Container: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
[15738 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p '/tmp/devcontainers-0327dd97-9f05-4d50-9aad-362e3dbbd3d21677285351669' && cat > '/tmp/devcontainers-0327dd97-9f05-4d50-9aad-362e3dbbd3d21677285351669/env-loginInteractiveShell.json' << 'envJSON'
[15748 ms] 
[15749 ms] 
[15825 ms] *
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
[15835 ms] Server bound to 127.0.0.1:33379 (IPv4)
Extension host agent listening on 33379

[15836 ms] Start: Run in container: echo 33379 >'/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.devport-441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf'
[15840 ms] 
[15841 ms] 
[15841 ms] Port forwarding for container port 33379 starts listening on local port.
[15844 ms] Port forwarding local port 33379 to container port 33379
[15859 ms] Start: Run in container: # Test for /root/.gitconfig and git
[15864 ms] /root/.gitconfig exists
[15865 ms] 
[15865 ms] Exit code 1
[15870 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --global --replace-all credential.helper '!f() { /root/.vscode-server/bin/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-ae25993f01fb68030d008f6a89607c8a1ba3a4a7.js git-credential-helper $*; }; f' || true
[15883 ms] 
[15885 ms] 
[15907 ms] Port forwarding connection from 52920 > 33379 > 33379 in the container.
[15908 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf/node -e 
[16250 ms] [00:36:09] 




[16414 ms] [00:36:10] Extension host agent started.
[16832 ms] Port forwarding 52920 > 33379 > 33379 stderr: Connection established
[16858 ms] Port forwarding connection from 52925 > 33379 > 33379 in the container.
[16859 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf/node -e 
[16888 ms] [00:36:10] [127.0.0.1][2f1249b3][ManagementConnection] New connection established.
[17646 ms] Port forwarding 52925 > 33379 > 33379 stderr: Connection established
[19459 ms] [00:36:13] [127.0.0.1][eeed07a7][ExtensionHostConnection] New connection established.
[19469 ms] [00:36:13] [127.0.0.1][eeed07a7][ExtensionHostConnection] <238> Launched Extension Host Process.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you have both `"twxs.cmake"` and `"josetr.cmake-language-support-vscode"`? Shouldn't you only need one of those?

Comment: @user You are probably right, I like `"twxs.cmake"` for the autoformatting. Based on the popularity of `"josetr.cmake-language-support-vscode"`, I feel like it must bring something else to the table but am not sure specifically what. I'll try `twxs` alone and see if I notice a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had somehow corrupted the ssl certificate (or downloaded the wrong format) I generated from Chrome. Once I regenerated it, my dev containers installed all the correct extensions.

The correct certificate looked something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
~snip~
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to manually install extensions after it is built? If so, I had  similar issue that was solved by adding the following `environment` var to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
environment:
   - NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<path/to/certificate>
```

This [post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2987) provides additional context.

Answer (score -1):

My solution to this problem was to add an environment variable as a remoteEnv in .devcontainers.json file.

```
{
 ....
    "remoteEnv": {
        "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED": "0"
    },
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-dev-cli-apps:latest",
....
}
```