# Include Private Key With Certificate in web request running NodeJS on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, https, ssl-certificate

I need to authenticate my GET request to an API by providing a certificate with the web request.

I am using NodeJS running on a Windows client.

The request is failing, apparently due to the need to include the private key in plain text, which I do not have available to me.

Am I missing a way to use an X509 with the key embedded (not plain text)?

I can get the full certificate with the private key in a couple of ways, but I cannot get the private key in plain text.

I have tried the [WIN-CA](https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca) NPM module, but [it does not deal with private keys](https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca/issues/31).

Any ideas, confirmation of the issue, and solutions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in rather a round-about way. Part of the issue is that our certificate authority is an internal provider.

To solve the issue we:

- We updated the old code to the Node.js [https module.](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_https.asp)
- We then added the [win-ca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-ca) module to inject the corporate certificate authorities.
- We used [win-cert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-cert) module to obtain the certificate with private key.

Node that We did not want to copy the certificate to the file system, so using `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` [and similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283040/how-to-add-custom-certificate-authority-ca-to-nodejs) was not preferred.

Code extract:

```
const https = require('https');
const winCert = require('win-cert');
require('win-ca/api')({store: ['root', 'ca'], inject: true});

const certOptions = {
    storeName: 'My',
    storeLocation: 'LocalMachine',
    thumbprint: '098d3.....'
};

const httpOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
    }
};


const certAndKey = winCert.getCertificate(certOptions).then((resolve, reject) => {
    certObtained = true;
    httpOptions.cert = resolve.cert;
    httpOptions.key = resolve.key;
});

const dpmRequest = https.request(httpOptions, ...
```

*Note that if the process is not running as admin, or if the certificate is not marked as exportable, the key will not be accessible.*