# "unable to verify the first certificate" when connecting to elasticsearch from nodejs using self-generated certificates

Tags: node.js, docker, express, elasticsearch, ssl

How do I connect to my elasticsearch cluster (TLS secured) when there are certificates generated by myself with the `elasticsearch-certutil`?

[According to the ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-connecting.html#auth-tls) this code snippet should do it:

```js
const client = new Client({
  node: config.elastic.node,
  auth: {
    username: "elastic",
    password: config.elastic.password
  },
  tls: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync( "./share/es/certs/ca.crt" ),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, this gives me this famous error:

```bash
ConnectionError: unable to verify the first certificate
```

I've setup ES via docker-compose. To wrap up, I did the following:

1. Generating the certs using the `elasticsearch-certutil` using `cert` command via: `bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem --in config/instances.yml -out /certs/bundle.zip`. `instances.yml` contains all of my nodes as well as kibana. `bundle.zip` contains all certs and keys as well as the certificate for CA.
2. Configuring my nodes in `docker-compose.yml` so that they can read the generated certificates. For instance,

   ```json
      ...
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=${ES_CERTS_DIR}/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=${ES_CERTS_DIR}/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=${ES_CERTS_DIR}/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=${ES_CERTS_DIR}/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=${ES_CERTS_DIR}/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=${ES_CERTS_DIR}/es01/es01.key
      ...
   ```
3. Validating the connection with curl with this command

   ```bash
   $ curl -X GET "https://elastic:$ES_PASSWORD@my-cluster-doomain.com:9201" -H "Content-type: application/json" --cacert $CACERT --key $KEY --cert $CERT
   ```

   where `$CACERT`, `$KEY`, `$CERT` are pointing to the CA cert, the key and certificate for the node that I am connecting to. This results in:

   ```json
   {
     "name" : "es01",
     "cluster_name" : "es-docker-cluster",
     ...
     "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
   }
   ```

   which is fine I suppose.

But why can't I connect to my cluster from my expressjs application? I read something about [creating a the certificate chain](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31725#issuecomment-617115129) and letting ES know that. But, I this necessary? I mean, I can connect via `curl` and also using `elasticdump`. What gives my an error is when I access the cluster via browser https://my-cluster-domain.com:9201. The browser warns me that, although the certificate is valid, the connection is not secure.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after [a lot of googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=elasticsearch-certutil+%22unable+to+verify+the+first+certificate%22) it turned out that adding the CA file to the ES client config is not enough, as indicated in my example configuration above.

```js
  ...
  tls: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync( "./share/es/certs/ca.crt" ),
    rejectUnauthorized: false  # don't do this in production
  }
```

Instead, one has to announce the CA certificate to the Node process itself, before configuring your connecting to ES. You can do this, as described [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47160447/1283512) and [in this post (solution 2a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020493/1283512), with the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` [environment variable](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file). I now start my process like this and it worked out:

```bash
$ NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="./share/es/certs/ca.crt" NODE_ENV=prod ...
```

One last remark, you don't have to set `rejectUnauthorized: false`, [as some workarounds do](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/1208), in case you have the current version of the elasticsearch client.

My final configuration looks like this:

```
  const client = new Client({
    node: config.elastic.node,
    auth: {
      username: "elastic",
      password: config.elastic.password
    }
  })
```

Comment: i am going nuts over this as well. can i please pay your weight in gold to help me fix this? if so, please drop me an email at mihairaulea [[[att]]] gmail.com

Comment: Perfect! NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable fixed the problem.