# How to add custom certificate authority (CA) to nodejs via terminal

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to add a custom certificate and the comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47160447/2685781 says to run:

```
$ export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=[your CA certificate file path]
```

So I run:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:/user/me/etc/ca-certificate.crt
```

When I run it in Visual Studio Code i get this error:

```
export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

And when I run it in Node.js command prompt i get this error:

```
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So how exactly where and how do I run it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using windows system based on the error.

you can try this

```
cmd /C "set "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:/user/me/etc/ca-certificate.crt" && npm start"
```

Comment: Ah yes it's on windows.

When I run that in Node.js command prompt I get:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\andah/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\andah\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: make sure you are at the right project location. `cd <path-to-project>` and then run this command

Comment: Now I at least don't get an error, but nothing seems to happen. Do you know how I can check if it's set?